# I am getting Invalid regular expression error while running npm start

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I have recently installed the expo. I have created a project using expo init.
After creation when I running npm start I am getting below error please slove my issue

```
> @ start C:\Users\ujwal\Desktop\Java\my-new-project
> expo start

Starting project at C:\Users\ujwal\Desktop\Java\my-new-project
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
error Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ujwal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-07T11_19_27_567Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Please share your node, expo version.

Comment: "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "expo-cli": "^2.10.1",
    "package": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",

Answer (score 42, accepted):

you have to make change in this file `{project_root}\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js`

there is an invalid regular expression that needed changed. I changed the first expression under `sharedBlacklist` from:

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

to

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

hope it'll helps you....

Comment: Yeah, it did work, but can you explain what caused this error? i just moved my project from one directory to another. and it was working perfectly in my previous directory but i had to do this after moving it to new directory.

Comment: @KashanHaider it stucks on loading graph

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you are experiencing this error: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26598. Per the issue ticket, you have some alternatives:

First option: downgrade to node 10.16.3 LTS

Second option: if you use Yarn, add a 'resolutions' property to your package.json to point to the metro-config version where the issue is fixed:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "metro-config": "0.57.0"
  },
```

Third option: if you use npm instead of yarn, you need to find a way to fix the "metro-config" sub-dependency to "0.57.0". I don't know how to do that, maybe npm-shrinkwrap can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using react (and not react-native) on Windows, got the same issue. Fixed it with a newer version of node.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24564450)

Comment: @SuleymanSah This answer doesn't either critique or request clarification from the author.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue today after installing a new expo-template-tabs project and then running `expo start`.

You will need to make change in the file:

```
{project_root}\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js
```

There is an invalid regular expression that needed to be changed. So please change this:

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

to

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

As seen on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58880918/12384847) provided by Kishan Gujarati.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer should be a comment, as it refers to an answer to another question.

Comment: I tried to add a comment to Kishans Post but it wouldn't let me. It said "You must have 50 reputation to comment"

Comment: No problem. I suggested an edit to your answer. Try to keep it like that if you are referring to an answer in another question.